# Token Mismatch Exception , if a form is open in browser for long time

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks, token

I know what is TokenMismatchException exeptions but how I resolve the issue if a form is open for a long time and then suddenly you fill the form and submit it then it also throws the same TokenMismatchException, is there any solution for not show such an error.The session expires after some time if the form page is left idol for a long time and then submit it. that is all.

Comment: you can increase csrf token expire time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to increase session time in your application's `config/session.php` file.

```
/*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Lifetime
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
    | to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
    | to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
    |
    */

    'lifetime' => 120,

    'expire_on_close' => false,
```

Comment: I will increase the session time also.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add TokenMismatchException in app\Exceptions\Handler.php

```
use Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler {

public function render($request, Exception $e) {


         if ($e instanceof TokenMismatchException){
            //redirect to a form when there is token mismatch
            return redirect($request->fullUrl())->with('alert-warning',"Opps! Seems you couldn't submit form for a longtime. Please try again");
        }

        //Remaining code 
        .
        .
        .
        .

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this change and will reply if it works find.

Comment: @MutahirShah have you try that ?

Comment: Yes , I change my exception with your code , but I did not test the login because I start working on another project . I will check it and will test it. Actually I did not faced the problem second time therefore I did notice your exception message.